# How to get the text file from SFTP server and stored in local in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, sftp

I'm trying to fetch text file from the SFTP server and store in my local can you.

Note: The code is needed in VBScript.
This is a commercial version. I have tried

```
Function MISC_FTPUpload(byVal sSite, byVal sUsername, byVal sPassword, byVal sLocalFile, byVal sRemotePath, byRef sError)

Const OpenAsDefault = -2
Const FailIfNotExist = 0
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim oFTPScriptFSO
Dim oFTPScriptShell
Dim sOriginalWorkingDirectory
Dim sFTPScript
Dim sFTPTemp
Dim bRetCode
Dim sFTPTempFile
Dim oFTPScript
Dim sResults
Dim sOut
Dim sCmd

LOG_Write "MISC_FTPUpload called at: " & Now

Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sRemotePath = Trim(remothpath)
sLocalFile = Trim(localpath)


If InStr(sRemotePath, " ") > 0 Then
    If Left(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" And Right(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" Then
          sRemotePath = """" & sRemotePath & """"
    End If
End If

If InStr(sLocalFile, " ") > 0 Then
    If Left(sLocalFile, 1) <> """" And Right(sLocalFile, 1) <> """" Then
          sLocalFile = """" & sLocalFile & """"
    End If
End If


If Len(sRemotePath) = 0 Then
    'Please note that no premptive checking of the
    'remote path is done. If it does not exist for some
    'reason, Unexpected results may occur.
    sRemotePath = "\"
End If

If InStr(sLocalFile, "*") Then
    If InStr(sLocalFile, " ") Then
        sError = "Error: Wildcard uploads do not work if the path contains a space." & vbNewLine & "This is a limitation of the Microsoft FTP client."
          LOG_Write sError
          MISC_FTPUpload = False
          Exit Function
    End If
ElseIf Len(sLocalFile) = 0 Or Not oFTPScriptFSO.FileExists(sLocalFile) Then

    sError = "Error: File Not Found."
    LOG_Write sError
    MISC_FTPUpload = False
    Exit Function
End If



sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option batch on" & vbCRLF
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option confirm off"& vbCrLf  
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option transfer binary" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & sftpuser & ":" & passsftp & "@" & sftphostname & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & sftp server path & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "put " & localpath & vbCRLF
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "close" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "exit" & vbCrLf

LOG_Write "Script for FTP File: " & vbNewLine & sFTPScript

sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName
LOG_Write "FTP Input file stored at: " & sFTPTempFile


Set oFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
oFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
oFTPScript.Close
Set oFTPScript = Nothing  

sCmd = """C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" -script=" & sFTPTempFile 
MISC_RunCmd sCmd, sOut, sError
LOG_Write sOut

Wscript.Sleep 1000


oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)


If sError = ""  And InStr(sOut, "binary") >0  And InStr(sOut, "100%") >0 Then
    MISC_FTPUpload = True
Else
    sError = "Error: " & sError
    LOG_Write sError
    MISC_FTPUpload = False 
End If

Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
End Function`
```

But I'm not getting any response.

Comment: *"not getting any response"* - what does that mean? + What is an exact value of `sCmd` before you execute it? What is an exact contents of the `sFTPTempFile`?

Comment: You are missing quotes in a lot of your code: `sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & buildsftp & ":" & 9D2GRGCu & "@" & sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com & vbCrLf` should be `sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & buildsftp & ":" & "9D2GRGCu" & "@" & "sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com" & vbCrLf` for example. `"cd " & \\sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com\dummy\ldapfulltab.txt & vbCrLf`-> `"cd \\sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com\dummy\ldapfulltab.txt" & vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 1):

One important problem in your script is that it expects the `C:\Websites\SFTP\put.txt` file to exist locally before downloading it:

```
ElseIf Len(sLocalFile) = 0 Or Not oFTPScriptFSO.FileExists(sLocalFile) Then
    sError = "Error: File Not Found."
    LOG_Write sError
    MISC_FTPUpload = False
    Exit Function
End If
```

If the file doesn't exist, your code will exit here.

One other thing is that your Function gets parameters (`sSite`, `sUsername`, `sPassword`, etc) that you should use in the function. Instead, you overwrite `sRemotePath` and `sLocalFile` right away. It might be because you were troubleshooting but other parameters don't seem to be used either.

There are other problems with quotes in the following lines:

```
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & buildsftp & ":" & 9D2GRGCu & "@" & sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & \\sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com\dummy\ldapfulltab.txt & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "put " & C:\Websites\SFTP\put.txt & vbCRLF
```

Should be something like this at least but you should be using your parameters here:

```
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & buildsftp & ":" & "9D2GRGCu" & "@" & "sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & "\\sftp-qa.ebs.thomsonreuters.com\dummy\ldapfulltab.txt" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "put " & sLocalFile & vbCrLf
```

Comment: Hi Etienne -thank you for your help can you please suggest any sample coding to access SFTP server it would be very useful for me

Comment: You seem to be using WinSCP to handle the commands you build in your script. That should support SFTP. You can have WinSCP generate a script template for you: [Generating script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating). Once you have a script that works, you can compare your code with the script and make any adjustments.